# Why does my AutoSuggestBox open at random?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a UWP/xaml application. I use AutoSuggestBox on many screens, often several of them on a screen.

I have a problem where the suggestions for one or more of these controls pop open at unwanted times, usually when a screen first renders. Nobody has clicked or tapped on the control. Furthermore, it appears to be in a weird state in which the suggestion list seems to be floating above the window containing the control, often extending outside of that window.

The problem is not consistent. I've identified a few paths that make it happen frequently, but there doesn't seem to be any explanation as to why it is happening sometimes on some controls but not others.

Frank

Comment: I tested several AutoSuggestBoxs, the suggestion list didn't pop at unwanted times and also didn't extend outside of the window. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Difficult for me to extract a simple example. I think the problem is related to threading because it mostly happens when there is no network connection, which also means that my app is not trying to await network responses while it populates the AutoSuggestBoxes.

Comment: Should an AutoSuggestBox open at a time other than when it receives the focus? In other words, should it open when its options change or some other action occurs?

Comment: Also, my app is a UWP app. I have noticed that things sometimes work differently in UWP than they do in .NET.

Comment: In general, when users enter text using a keyboard or pen, the relevant suggestion lists will be opened to choose.

Comment: Would assigning a value to the AutoSuggestBox's Text property cause the suggestions to appear?

Comment: I'm frequently ending up with four or five different AutoSuggestBox suggestion lists open simultaneously. It doesn't happen all the time, but when it happens it is always because the control has some predefined value in the Text field (i.e. i'm setting it up to edit an existing record). So I suspect that setting the initial value is part of the problem, but I don't know why it only happens some of the time, or what else I can do about it.

Comment: You can listen the TextChanged event, then check the value of Text when the event is triggered, if the value is empty, you could explicitly set AutoSuggestBox.ItemsSource as null, the suggestion list appears only if the ItemsSource has a value.